# Producing a user defined R function (or nesting several functions) to subset original dataframe into new dataframes for each individual

Tags: r, function, loops, subset, user-defined-functions

I have what is likely a ridiculously easy problem in R, but my lack of experience in writing user defined functions doesn't help.

**Example data**

```
individual = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), measure1 = c(40, 
70, 90, 100, 40, 70, 90, 100), measure2 = c(1.06, 0.7, 0.507, 
0.37, 0.9, 0.56, 0.412, 0.375)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

**What I'm trying to do**

In short, I want to create user a defined function that can do the following:

1. Take a dataframe, subset the data such that only the relevant rows for measurement 1 and 2 are left.
2. Take the subset data and create a new dataframe for each individual in the dataset.
3. on each new dataframe, create a linear model in the following form `lm(measure1~measure2, data)`

**My thoughts/what I have tried**
First off it's probably worth me clearing *why* I want a function to do this. Simply put, I have around 10 datasets that are similar. I want to perform these operations on all datasets. I *could* just create 1 big dataset and combine them, but the logistics are problematic. So, I decided that writing a function would be easier.

**Problem1**

```
Filt.data<- function(x,y,z){
new.data<<-x[x$measure1 %in% c(y,z), ]
new.data
}
```

The above code works great and allows me to input any dataframe "x" and subset using variable y and z (which are two values of measure 1). It's a good first step, but this clearly produces a new dataframe with the data for all participants 1:i. So, my next step was to nest a for loop in the function. I came up with the following

```
filt.data<- function(x,y,z){
for (i in 1:length(x$participant)){
x[x$measure1 %in% c(y,z), ]
}
}
```

This is far as I have got. The thing that is stumping me at this point is how to create a new dataframe for each participant 1:i that is named uniquely (ie., new.dat_1) where the "1" is the number of the participant (or something similar).Once I have done this step I would be able to simply run the linear model over the dataframes as a list I think? But then I run into the same problem again: How do I create a variable to store the results for each linear model?

I'm pretty new to R and don't use it all that frequently. I have tried looking up similar problems, but it's the whole indexing [[i]] notation that just screws me over! So, quick request: if anyone feels they are able to produce the code, could they also add little notes? This will help me massively for being able to do this again in the future, and understand the mechanics.

As always, thank you to the heros out there who take the time out of their day to (1) read this and (2) offer support!

Cheers.

Comment: Simple approach: use `assign()` in a loop over individuals and subset the main data frame in each interation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good practice to

- Write to global environment from inside the function. Avoid using `<<-` or `assign`.
- Create individual dataframes for each `individual`. You should use list instead.

Try this approach :

```
Filt.data<- function(x,y,z) {
  dat <- subset(x, measure1 %in% c(y,z))
  lapply(split(dat, dat$individual), function(x) lm(measure1~measure2, x))
}

list_model <- Filt.data(df, 40, 70)
list_model

#$`1`

#Call:
#lm(formula = measure1 ~ measure2, data = x)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)     measure2  
#     128.33       -83.33  


#$`2`

#Call:
#lm(formula = measure1 ~ measure2, data = x)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)     measure2  
#     119.41       -88.24
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(individual = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 measure1 = c(40, 70, 90, 100, 40, 70, 90, 100), 
                 measure2 = c(1.06, 0.7, 0.507, 0.37, 0.9, 0.56, 0.412, 0.375))
```

Comment: This is excellent @Ronak Shah! Exactly what I was looking for and worked perfectly. Excuse me for being a little cheeky here, but could you possibly explain what is happening in the code, so I can better understand for next time? I get lost at the `lapply` stage where it says `function(x) lm(measure1~measure2`. I get that you have split the data by participant, but what is `dat` if the dataframe is called `df`? Similar what does `function(x)` do prior to `lm`? 

Thank you so much again for your help here!

Comment: `df` is the complete dataframe whereas `dat` is the subset of dataframe where only the values `y` and `z` are present. `function(x)` is called anonymous function which applies the `lm` function on each `individual` separately.

Comment: I just realised I was being blind :) My bad! Ok perfect. Thank you very much for your help on this. I always find that engaging this way ensures I don't just copy code blindly, and actually understand the mechanics so I can apply the same thought process to future problems!